# OWIN change "Date" header value

Tags: http, owin, katana

Is there any way to change value of Date header, returned in response? I tried to set header on `HttpResponse` message in WebAPI action.

When I do this in OWIN configuration

```
app.Use((c, a) =>
            {

                c.Response.OnSendingHeaders(o =>
                    {
                        c.Response.Headers.Clear();
                    }, null);
                return a();
            });
```

I still receive 3 headers:

```
Content-Length: 3705
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Sat, 29 Mar 2014 18:53:32 GMT
```

Is there any way to change value of them? Look like they are being set on very low level in pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

As per w3, origin server MUST include a Date header field in all responses, except in few cases. read here [more](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18)

If you check Katana code you will see there is a method called SendKnownResponseHeader in KatanaWorkerRequest class of Boot.AspNet namespace. So, yes it is added in the pipeline.

Wondering why you want to change these headers?